# C++ char* split with strtok not working

Tags: c++, char, fstream, strtok

Hi I am trying to make a simple reading from a text file. I need to split the strings hence I use strtok. However when I use char* as the strings, it just shows me an error.

Below is my code. Any advise?

```
void encrypt(fstream& afile,char* fileName,int size){
    string txt,tmp;
    int key[100][100],num,n=0,m=0;
    afile.open(fileName,ios::in);
    while (afile>>tmp)
    {
        txt = txt + tmp;
    }
    afile.close();
    afile.open("keyfile.txt",ios::in);
    char *pch = new char(100),*tmp2 = new char(100);
    while (afile>>tmp2)
    {
        pch = strtok (tmp2,";");

        while (pch != NULL)
        {
            key[n][m] = atoi(pch);
            cout<<key[n][m]<<" ";
            pch = strtok (NULL, ";");
            m++;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        n++;
    }
    delete []tmp2;  
    delete []pch;
    afile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This allocates a single char for both `pch` and `tmp2`, and sets that value to 100:

```
char *pch = new char(100),*tmp2 = new char(100);
```

What you want is this:

```
char *pch = new char[100];
char *tmp2 = new char[100];
```

But there is a memory leak, since you replace `pch` immediately with the return value of `strtok`.  So there is no need to allocate for `pch`.

In addition, you could have just declared an array of 100 chars for `tmp2` instead of dynamically allocating:

```
char tmp2[100];
```

So it all boils down to this:

```
char *pch;
char tmp2[100];
```

with no need for `delete[]` at the end of the function.